# How can I center align a Bootstrap dropdown properly?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I know that I can center a Bootstrap dropdown element by using the `text-align: center` CSS style. This centers the dropdown menu as desired. However, when I click the menu to activate it, and the list of items appears, it is instead aligned to the left of the parent `div`. I'd like to make the left edge of the dropdown menu flush with the left edge of the button that you click to activate it (like it would be if the dropdown was aligned to the left by default). Is this possible?

[This is a JSFiddle that demonstrates the issue I'm having.](http://jsfiddle.net/orr3cmgz/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the `dropdown` class as follows

```
.dropdown{ margin: 0 auto; display: table; }
```

if you do not wish to set a specific width for the element.

Answer (score 1):

The issue appears because `.dropdown-menu` is positioned absolutely (`left: 0`) to the parent container which still takes the full-width. You could set a fixed width for `div.dropdown` (103px just like the dropdown button) and also add `margin: 0 auto`, because if you don't, your button will not be centered anymore.

**CSS**

```
.dropdown{
    width:103px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y2nx8e93/1/)**

Comment: Thanks. I'd like to avoid fixed-size elements, but this does give the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

Use `margin-left` instead of `text-align:center`. It will work.